# Yii2 Advanced - Share session between frontend and mainsite (duplicate of frontend for www)

Tags: session, cookies, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, vhosts

I have a custom members system that I have made: [Yii2 Members System](https://github.com/WadeShuler/yii2-members-system). You can refer to that for full details, or install it so you can work with it for this question.

I have `frontend` and `backend` just as Yii2 provides, with a few modifications to separate the sessions/cookies so that `backend` works with the Admin model and pulls from an `admin` table. Similar to old traditional member systems.

`mainsite` is basically a clone of `frontend` and it's role is to be the main website. What you get when you go to `www.site.com` or `site.com`.

Here are the 3 apps and their example domains:

- **mainsite** = www.site.com or site.com
- **frontend** = users.site.com
- **backend** = admin.site.com

When a user logs in (`users.site.com/site/login`) and go back to the homepage (`mainsite` at `www.site.com`) I want it to know they are logged in and show their username. Just like how frontend operates by default from the advanced app.

From what I have so far, I login and head back to the mainsite and it just reads `An internal server error occurred.`. It doesn't look like a Yii error, but a server error? When I look in the Yii logs under runtime, it mentions access control:

```
2017-04-14 13:38:25 [127.0.0.1][1][-][error][yii\web\HttpException:403] exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed to perform this action.' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii2-members-system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/filters/AccessControl.php:151
```

---

Here are some of my configs.

**mainsite/config/main.php**

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => false,
    ],
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-mainsite',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\User',
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_identity-frontend',
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'domain' => '.yii2-members-system.dev',
        ],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain' => '.yii2-members-system.dev',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
],
```

**frontend/config/main.php**

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'bundles' => false,
    ],
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'common\components\User',
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_identity-frontend',
            'httpOnly' => true,
            'domain' => '.yii2-members-system.dev',
        ],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
        'cookieParams' => [
            'domain' => '.yii2-members-system.dev',
            'httpOnly' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
        ],
    ],
],
```

**vhosts**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yii2-members-system.dev
    ServerAlias yii2-members-system.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii2-members-system/mainsite/web"
    ErrorLog "logs/mainsite.yii2-members-system.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/mainsite.yii2-members-system.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yii2-members-system.dev
    ServerAlias admin.yii2-members-system.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii2-members-system/backend/web"
    ErrorLog "logs/admin.yii2-members-system.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/admin.yii2-members-system.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yii2-members-system.dev
    ServerAlias users.yii2-members-system.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/yii2-members-system/frontend/web"
    ErrorLog "logs/users.yii2-members-system.dev-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/users.yii2-members-system.dev-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I think this is example bad choose Yii2 template. Why advanced template ? may be better Yii2 basic template + modules ? That's all you could do faster by Yii-basic-template. Advanced is choosed when sessions, cookies, etc separation is needed

Comment: Because this completely separates each segment: main website, user dashboard, admin dashboard, api, mailer, etc. etc... It allows each section to operate 90% independent of all the others. If I break something in admin dashboard, it usually doesn't affect the user dashboard. The more separation between the user and admin code, the better for security. -- You could have admin (`backend`) app using a different user for the database that has access to the admin table. So if your exploited, they can't mess with the admin table from the user section.

Answer (score 1):

You can share session between subdomain or main domain. As per yii configuration, you need to configure like below in **frontend/config/main.php** and **mainsite/config/main.php**.

```
'request' => [
    'csrfParam' => '_csrf-app',
],
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity', 'httpOnly' => true, 'domain'=>'.yii2-members-system.dev', 'path'=>'/'],
],
'session' => [
    'name' => 'sessionName',
    'savePath'=> __DIR__ . '/../../sessionTmp'
],
```

In this configuration, session name, session save path, identity cookie path and domain should match with other subdomain to share session between two yii app.

So create one tmp folder inside your app and point it to session save path. like above.

I hope, this will help.

Comment: Thanks, but I got it working. The issue was my `mainsite` (usually for guests as it's the main website homepage) had in the AccessControl to allow to guests.. lol duh, they aren't guests after they go to `frontend` and login. Hence, I didn't meet the access rules because I wasn't a guest. Removed that line and boom it worked. --- By the way, you don't need to set the `path` or the `savePath`. The config as I listed above works just fine.