# Yii2 advanced app with shared session do not auto login on session timeout

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new here.I have an issue related to shared sessions on Yii2 advanced template.

I have an yii2 advanced application with 4 subapps:

```
frontend - landing page, login
backend - admin panel
customer - panel for customers
provider - panel for providers
```

I have an application where I always login from `frontend` application, and depending on my `role` I am redirected to `customer`, `provider` or `backend` applications.

Everything works fine, until my session times out. In those three inner applications I become unauthorized user. Refreshing the page does nothing, however when I open `frontend` page, and try to login again, the `frontend` does not show me the Login Form, instead it redirects me to one of those apps with new session.

Seeing that it does not ask me credentials again, it seems that I can auto login using `frontend` app, but auto login does not work in other three applications..

I've made shared session for all of my apps using answer in this issue:
[Yii2 Advanced - Share session between frontend and mainsite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43445780/9895666)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `enableAuoLogin` parameter is turned on in all of your applications?

```
'enableAutoLogin' => true,
```

If yes, even though you shared session between applications, when you first executed `php init` command (for yii2-advanced), notice that it generates different `cookieValidationKey`'s for each application. Those validation keys are used for auto-login process. As you have same cookies for all of your applications, then `cookieValidationKey`'s should be the same as well.

Those validation keys are stored in `main-local.php` config file for each application (`frontend`, `backend` folders.. in your case, I guess, you have extra `customer` and `provider` folders)

One of the solutions is to copy-paste `cookieValidationKey` from `frontend/config/main-local.php`, to other `main-local.php` files. Ideally you have to change your `init` file in root-folder, make it generate one single `cookieValidationKey` for all your modules/applications.

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you! I decreased session timeout and checked, seems it worked!